# java.security.ProviderException: Could not initialize NSS

Tags: java, security, opensuse

I'm receiving the error "Could not initialize NSS" in my java application when sending an HTTPS Request. Unfortunally I do not have the complete stack trace of the exception in my log, but from what I have already googled, it is most probably caused by the missing shared object "libnss3.so".

Does anyone know which package I need to install on open suse to get the shared object in the right place ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can help to solve the problem.

[Could not initialize NSS](http://www.unnaki.com/2011/07/libnss3-so-error-on-debian-wheezy/)

Comment: yes, I saw that page, but what package do I need on opens suse?

Comment: http://pkgs.org/download/libnss3.so check for the appropriate package given in that link

Comment: not yet, the library is installed now, but the error is still there. I need to change the application to print the whole stack trace to get further information.

Comment: Now have the Exception:Caused by: java.io.IOException: /usr/lib/libnss3.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
 at sun.security.pkcs11.Secmod.nssLoadLibrary(Native Method)
 at sun.security.pkcs11.Secmod.initialize(Secmod.java:203)
 at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:197)

Comment: I installed accedently the 32 bit library, with the 64 bit library it works now

Comment: On Ubuntu 11.04 with Zend Studio, the nssLibraryDirectory was set to the libnss3.so file within ZS, instead of a directory.

Looking at the result of a find / -name libnss3.so, I saw the system had a version of that file directly below /usr/lib, so I set nssLibraryDirectory = /usr/lib

...and this worked. This might be a more general solution: find the file on disk and replace nssLibraryDirectory with the directory containing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FGM.
I had the same problem, and your advise has worked despite I'm using Slackware.

Comment: By the way the file is inside the `/etc/java/` directory, and the change was set `nssLibraryDirectory = /usr/lib/` instead of `nssLibraryDirectory = /usr/lib/seamonkey/`.

Comment: The URL can not be opened

Comment: Archived page is http://web.archive.org/web/20111119055404/http://www.unnaki.com/2011/07/libnss3-so-error-on-debian-wheezy/